# where to find trustworthy peer nodes

Tags: baking, solo-baking, foundation-nodes

Where can I find a list of trustworthy peer node hostnames and/or ip addresses?

The only list I have is just the TF nodes which gives me a total of 6 nodes. I have my expected number of connections set to 40 (seems reasonable?), but currently am only connected to 23 and keep seeing warnings:

`p2p.maintenance: Too few connections (23)`

Things are still working, but I'm just wondering where or how to find trusted nodes.

Is using just the TF nodes sufficient?

I'd rather have a more diverse (more decentralized) list of peers.

Comment: if you aren't running a private node, this process should be automatic. https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/444/too-few-connections-config-js

Comment: it's a private node, thanks though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use as many peers as you can, for a more secure approach you can use a private node that connects to your public nodes instead.

List with nodes: [Tzscan Network](https://tzscan.io/network)

Script to add peers: [addPeers](https://gist.github.com/utdrmac/2125a8514960e163837e86bc934f19b6)